# How to clean uninstall flutter fvm package

Tags: flutter, dart, fvm

which folder has to be delete for clean uninstall FVM package/Flutter Version Management ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First apply the official uninstallation steps in the following [page](https://fvm.app/docs/getting_started/installation/) in the official docs for the package, select the platform from the taps above and check the Uninstall section.

If you want to also delete all the configs of **FVM** along with all the installed **SDKs**, you can type the following in the Terminal/Command Prompt:

```
fvm config
```

You will see an output similar to the following:

```
FVM Settings:
Located at C:\Users\moaze\fvm\.settings

cachePath: D:\Development\Flutter-SDK\versions
skipSetup: false
gitCache: false
```

You can see to paths in the output, one for the FVM Settings and one for the SDKs which is `cachePath`, you can delete both folders.

Comment: when I tried the command, I got similar path but there's nothing in that path. Tried restarting, but still getting the same path as the command result

Answer (score 0):

From an elevated *(Ran as administrator)* PowerShell, run this command:

```
choco uninstall fvm
```